# SOS! The Great Anime.SE Mascot Idol Search!

Tags: discussion

For the inevitable launch of our site community we need to come up with a mascot design to help us promote ourselves.

To the community, I'd like to ask you to share your ideas on what kind of mascot would best promote and represent and promote community.

They can be just about anything, lolis, chibis, robots, animals, ships, etc. Be creative and try you best at creating a new, original concept. It doesn't matter if you can draw or not, even a description is fine.

Please try to follow this format when proposing an mascot:

> **Name**: (What is the name of your Mascot)
>
> **Description**: (Description of the mascot, provide any background behind you character and/or why you chose to create them)
>
> **Charm Point**: (What is the "trademarked" aspect of them that sets them apart? It can be a pose a catchphrase, an special action/attack pose, or something else all together)
>
> (Anything else you wish to include. E.g., Hobbies, blood-type, extended family, favorite food, favorite anime/manga, whatever idols do, etc.)

The top voted mascot suggestion may be commissioned into a work for the our site launch.

Try to keep things safe for work and do your best for the future of our community!

I'm looking forward to what everyone has to offer!

Comment: I thought we already had Sakamoto, the fire-breathing walrus...

Comment: Maybe we should have periodically changing mascots. For a lot of the fansub sites, I enjoy seeing a different banner and mascot on every refresh.

Comment: @Mysticial that would not be very maintainable in the long run. Once we decide on a character, maybe we can use different "versions" of it for promotion purpose.

Comment: while I'm thinking about moe character, I think it's a good to choose a character that related with Q&A such as detective character for example like [Conan](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-KRCdnZ_7ou4/UfX4Ar4RAXI/AAAAAAAAkr0/pw7MOYiGbRE/s1600/150510-detective-conan-conan-cover.jpg)... But it's just my opinion...

Comment: Should we really be coming up with full character proposals? I have a few ideas for points or aspects of a character, but I definitely couldn't flesh them out into a full character, and I'm not sure that would be the most useful thing anyway for @Jin and whoever ends up designing the character.

Comment: As a side suggestion, I think that once we have our mascot, we should rename and re-avatar the Community bot to w/e we chose. Give them a bit more purpose/presence/

Comment: IMO we should have multiple bot characters different from site's mascot, each with their own personality and active in different times of the day. Would feel like there's a lively gang working in the HQ.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. I'm guessing it has to be original.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused as to why we even _need_ a mascot in the first place. Do any other SE sites have one? And if we do need a mascot, why does the mascot need a "description" or a "charm point"? Surely the mascot will just be part of the imagery that shows up in the site's design?

Comment: Each site represents a certain community with special needs, catering to which could greatly improve overall user experience and the site's value. For example, mathematically-themed SE sites have cool formula markdown, and the UX site has a really great interface, as expected from UX fans. Personally, I don't know of a popular anime and manga themed community that doesn't have a mascot. It only seems natural to have one.

Comment: @user1306322 [MAL](http://myanimelist.net/), [Crunchyroll](http://www.crunchyroll.com/), /a/, [/r/anime](http://www.reddit.com/r/anime), [AniDB](http://anidb.net/), [MangaUpdates](http://www.mangaupdates.com/), and [AnimeNewsNetwork](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/) all lack mascots AFAIK (granted, some of these may not meet your definition of "community"). Can you give some examples of anime-themed communities that do have mascots? Because I wasn't aware that was really a thing.

Comment: In any case, if we are going to have a mascot, I still don't see why we need anything besides visual features like "red hair" or whatever. All of the answers so far have some sort of elaborate life story for the mascot characters, which strikes me as really excessive.

Comment: I guess we just need to come up with a better list requirements for the mascot then, with reasons explained for each requirement.

Comment: If Appearance is kept then Personality should be aswell since explaining one's personality will help in how the character is drawn particularly with facial expressions

Comment: I think we might need to take a step back and research more what site mascots are all about and come up with a more detailed set of requirements. AND get more attention from active users somehow.

Comment: For example, maybe create a huge list of various character traits, vote on them and select from the most prominent ones. Try different combos, see what looks appropriate.

Comment: Well, this hasn't got anywhere. I'm sure if we ask some people on SE outside A&M they'll at least give us a hint on how to go about creating a mascot char for a site.

Answer (score 5):

**Name:** Ai-chan

**Description:** Highschool detective. Carries a magnifying glass wherever she goes and determined to find out answers to all of Anime & Manga Stack Exchange's questions!

Having moved on from simple highschool mysteries, Ai now works as professional sleuth and tries to solve all of A&M's puzzling questions. She's still a highschool student though, so she mightn't get all of them ^^;

Raggedy hazelnut hair and wears a pale blue sailor fuku uniform (could have a summer version also).

[image]

When she's not solving mysteries, you can find Ai unwinding with a good light novel/manga on the sofa.

**Charm Point**: Very enthusiastic about finding answers and always tries her hardest. She gets very upset when she can't find an answer to a question (it's cute though).

When stuck on a particularly hard mystery, Ai scrunches her face up in intense consentration until she has a vivid realisation. I can imagine an exclamation mark over her head when she finds a solution

**Blood Type**: A

**Age**: 17

**Star Sign**: Gemini

**Favourite Anime/Manga:** Lupin III

Comment: She also owns an adorable tiny pet mech that helps her with quick facts and analysis?

Comment: ooh, that could be neat :)

Answer (score 1):

**Name:** Hina-Chan

*Appearance:* [Vegetable green hair](http://i196.photobucket.com/albums/aa227/Kyouki-chan93/GreenHair.jpg) *(Na in Hina can mean vegtables/greens)*, Purpelish eyes *(like in the picture before)* , about the size of [Squid Girl](http://fc03.deviantart.net/fs70/i/2011/007/2/b/squid_girl_by_sykeone-d36ma1v.jpg)

*Personality:* She has a radiant personality *(Another play on the name Hi can mean day/sun)*, always willing to help people. Always looking happy and ready to cheer you up. And very Adventurous/Curious.

*Background:* As she is not that old yet she sees every day as an adventure. Whenever possible she try's to learn new things, try new things out in her world wide exploration. Trying to turn everything into a Adventure.

**Charm Points:** Due to her bright personality, and curiosity she makes for a good hyper active cheery and adventurous girl (although this sometimes is quite tiring)
She is always trying to learn/find out new things.

She also is kind of clumsy at times, causing some of her adventures to be off short duration.

**Other:**

[*Blood type:* B](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_types_in_Japanese_culture)

*Hobbies:* Discovering new things, Going on trips.

*Family:* Family consists of her Father and Mother, And the last 4 years a Nephew also lived with them

Her mother is a Model for a swimsuit magazine, which often forces her to travel the globe. Hina joins her on these trips whenever she can

Her father runs a local local book store, selling all kinds of rare and antique books. Which Hina some times secretly reads through to find certain 'Treasure maps'

Her nephew is 3 years younger then her and often goes with her whens he goes out Exploring/adventuring. Due to him being younger he most often can't keep up and hurts himself somehow, making the duo return early from their adventures

*Favorite food:* Hina is a huge sweet tooth, with her favorites being [Pocky](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/88/Us-pocky.jpg) and [Botan rice candy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Botan_Rice_Candy)

*Least Favorite food:* Hina dislike's vegtables, and all foods that look green.

*Favorite book:* [Artemis fowl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artemis_Fowl_%28series%29), She also is trying to find a Fairy to extort gold from using Artemis as a guide to do so.

*Favorite Manga/anime:* One piece, she likes how they are searching for a huge treasure while adventuring to do so.

Answer (score 1):

***Se*iko-chan** (惺子), 18 years old, high-school student. (*name roughly means "sincere child"*)

She's knowledgeable, kind, honest, helping and straightforward. And good-looking, of course.

Seiko-chan represents the greatness of StackExchange community, and, in their turn, users are inspired to become great like her.

She loves experiencing various emotions the world of anime and manga can offer through inspiring adventures, fantasy, dramas; alluring romance, ero-manga; light-hearted comedy, slice of life; more serious seinen and josei, sci-fi, sports, and whatnot.

Seiko-chan's **favorite drink** is tea. Different kinds of tea, which perfectly fit the mood and allow for best entertainment experience.

She also enjoys cosplay and has some friends who share her infatuations.

Anime and manga just happen to be one of her main interests in entertainment. And so this is for many users, so don't forget to join [the Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) for some on- and off-topic discussion!

---

*[end of cool part]*

Forgive me if I messed up with the Japanese, for I am lvl 1 in it.

If anything, I'd go with Shaft's art style for realistic proportions, attractive body figure and serious, yet adventurous feeling. Along the lines of Hanekawa Tsubasa of Monogatari series.

I imagine it would be pretty awesome to have a random rotation of header backgrounds of Seiko-chan with various cups of tea, reading some manga or watching anime, if anyone is up to the task of drawing them.

Seiko-chan's friends could partake in her cosplay parties, parodying famous scenes and characters in the site's header and footer.

I'm opposed to cliche mascot characters with standard trademark elements, and StackExchange deserves much better. Which is why I thought of the above. Feel free to be inspired by this thought, and create your own unique proposition worthy of this site.

Comment: Are you sure about hentai part? Might not be favored by some people

Comment: instead of hentai (which means pervert in japanese from what i remember) you could use ero-manga or ero-works if you want to include anime and eroge (h games) as well, there is ero-manga (mainly doujin) which i wouldn't count as hentai but are more mature than your usual content, i equate this to the first 2 levels of classification used by Yuri-ism (level 3 contains nudity but no actual sex but i avoid that myself)

Comment: or you could use [Seinen manga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seinen), [Josei manga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josei_manga) or find a term which would include both

Answer (score -1):

**[万]{まん}[賀]{が}[河]{か} (Q-kun)**

- Gender: Male
- Age: 23
- DoB: 17/03/1993
- Blood type: O

Man Gaka is a chubby chibi manga character who draws manga for SEAM (Stack Exchange: Anime & Manga) to be adapted by A-chan. His name literally means "River of Ten Thousand Congratulations". His nickname, Q-kun, is a reference to his Quteness (cute as a pet) and his role as a Questioner. He is somewhat like a combination of Haruyuki Arita from *Accel World* and Albert "Al" Pitt from *Aria*.

Charm Points: As you may know, some mangaka write tidbits at the end of a manga volume. Q-kun does that, too, offering tips and reminders to question askers.

**[雨天]{うてん}[布達]{ふたつ} (A-chan)**

- Gender: Female
- Age: 17
- DoB: 24/04/1999
- Blood type: A

Uten Futatsu is an animated character and a mania. Uten means "rainy days" and Futatsu means "to make something known" or "that something that is made known". The A in her nickname is for Ame (rain) and Answers.

Charm Points: twintails (bluish-grey and sometimes braided) and a mild chuunibyou (中二病). She has the power to manipulate water, but is rather inexperienced at it that she sometimes accidentally floods Q-kun. I'll be honest and say that I had Edy Nelson from *Valkyria Chronicles* in mind when I conceived A-chan.

---

How I conceived Uten Futatsu: from アニメ, make the ア and メ revolve around the ニ so the katakanas change between アニメ and メニア. メニア sounds like mania, which describes many anime fans quite well. The ニ looks like 二 (pronounced ni or futatsu), hence the rather common personality of 中二病. アニメ minus the ニ is アメ, or rain. The revolving motion is called うんてん, which is very similar to うてん (has the kanji for rain, too).

Answer (score -2):

**Name: Dexter**

Info: A very skilled warrior. Very kind but can be annoying at times and thrives to become the best of the best though perseverance and love. Can be clumsy but that is what makes Dexter, Dexter. Also very talkative!

**Relations:**

Nanny Kate- His nannie: )

Claney Mihi- His Aunty : )

Best friends- Jamie and Shawn

Mum + Dad- Raiko + Tress

Hobbies: Enjoys eating, sleeping, having fun, being with family and fighting bad guys and loves to be a rebel to his principal.

**Age- 15**

Fav foods- He says 'gotta be everything'

Inspiration: @miharu-dante.

Fav anime: Full Metal Alchemist; Fairy Tail

---

Professions: Warrior/Mage and Sorceress

Strength: 3/5 Still needs training though

School: Capital Bay School for the Magic Arts

Best spell: Dazled Fury

Graduation Status: Not yet

Charm point: Loves to say "my time is now" and has a very bad history with lady's as he always goes awkward around them.

**Dexter says to pick him for Mascot. Working on an image to for him too. Not good at drawing though : )**

Answer (score -2):

**Names**: Azeru-kun (♂) and Aseko-chan (♀)

**Description**:

Azeru-kun and Aseko-chan are the fraternal twin ambassadors of Anime.SE. Azeru-kun is smart and reserved, he is very good at logical deductions and enjoys detective manga. Aseko-chan is a natural-born leader, she is a natural at any sports and likes adventure anime. Azeru-kun enjoys [sharp and deep conversations](https://anime.stackexchange.com/) and prefers to [settle arguments with negotiation](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/review) (though he usually ends up failing to do so), while Aseko-chan is [much more chatty](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) and [is quick to use her fists on arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banhammer) (to the annoyance of her brother).

Despite their personalities being almost exact opposite and despite their frequent fights, they are always very close with each other.

**Charm Point**:

Azeru-kun wears a diamond-shaped pendant (♦) and Aseko-chan wears a diamond-shaped hair clip (♦).

**Best friends**:

- [Doraemon](https://www.animenewsnetwork.co.uk/news/2008-03-14/doraemon-to-be-japan-first-anime-ambassador): Japan's Anime ambassador
- [The Unicorn](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122026/what-is-unicorn-on-stack-overflow): Meta ambassador

**Rivals**:

- [That noisy twins](http://www.google.com/search?q=kagamine%20twins&tbm=isch): they envy them since they are terrible singers
- [Sakamoto](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12178567#12178567)

**Azeru**

- Favorite genres: detective, shoujo, mecha, slice-of-life
- Likes: reading manga, [the Hiitachins](http://www.google.com/search?q=the%20hitachiin&tbm=isch) (he admires them as he thinks he's a gentlemen like them)
- Dislikes: [red graffiti](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/148108), cosplay, singing, his twin sister
- [180-degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/180-degree_rule): Left

**Aseko**

- Favorite genres: adventures, shounen, sports, horror
- Likes: her twin brother, watching anime, [red markers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/148108), putting costumes on Azeru
- Dislikes: singing, [the Hiitachins](http://www.google.com/search?q=the%20hitachiin&tbm=isch) (they creep her out)
- [180-degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/180-degree_rule): Right

---

I know zero Japanese, so I picked a Japanese-sounding name that somewhat rhymes with A.SE. If they turn out to mean something offensive, I apologize in advance, any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score -2):

**Name**: Sakamoto (Type Unicorn)

**Description**: Sakamoto is one of the the most charming unicorn you will ever see. While our site has meidos and lolis (also waifus), there's severe lack of unicorns. Unicorns have been a popular subject across many SE sites and SE meta memes.

Sakamoto is the gear that makes things turn, he digs through old questions and bumps up unanswered questions that have been buried under the sands of time. He sifts through the flags and delivers them to the moderators. He keeps tally on upvotes and downvotes. He the one responsible to compiling organizing the review queues, writing the labels to the tags and making sure the feeds arrive on time! He gives it his all so visitors from around the world can have a good time on this site! He's the one that gets things done behind the scenes!

[image: Sakamoto desu ga~]

<sub>*Design not final. May be subject to change. In case you are wondering where the original archetype comes from, this is the [unicorn](http://genesis-horizon.wikia.com/wiki/Unicorn) from 'The Horizon In the Middle of Nowhere' series. (I have yet to figure out an original design for him, so this serves as a placeholder for now.)*</sub>

**Charm Point**: Sakamoto's charm lies in this simple, nondescript design. There's enough detail for a shape, but not too much detail to bog him down. This makes him easy to draw and  be reproduced by others. His uses his magical horn (which doubles as a drill, a "giga-drill") to get things done around the site since he technically has no hands. While it doesn't seem like it, Sakamoto can actually fly thanks to his magical tail, which is actually a harisen.

He's round like [Bubbles](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/10/meet-bubbles/), the official SE mascot, but he's not flat, instead he's like fluffy and soft to touch, like a dango. He has little-bitty feet that go "clop-clop-clop" as he walks. His cute little eyes and button nose can disarm even the most unloving brutes. If he was a [Servant](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Servant) That cute radiant blush of his up his Charisma to A Rank (Saber only has Charisma that is B Rank) and light even the darkest of places.

*Blood Type*: O

*Birthday*: Dec. 11, 2012 (12/11/12)

Hobbies: Organizing the logistics of Anime.SE, spotlighting old questions so they can get answers, delivering bounties that have been awarded, handing out badges to helpful users, delivering notifications, delivering feeds to the chat rooms, and much much more~

**tl;dr: This site needs more unicorns.**

Comment: Unfortunately, there may have been to many pony-themed creatures ravaging the internet in the recent past. I'd like to see something more neutral or at least less fandom-specific. And more anime-themed in general.

Comment: -1 Sakamoto is a walrus

Comment: But really, Sakamoto is a black cat with a red scarf that lets him talk in Japanese.

Comment: I actually find the concept more "neutral" than some of the other ones listed here, tbh...